# Missing ) after argument list in Odoo QWeb xml file

Tags: xml, sorting, odoo, qweb

In a Odoo xml template file there is a t-foreach element like these:

```
<t t-foreach="widget.renderer.state.fields" t-as="field">
  <t t-esc="widget.renderer.state.fields[field].string" />
</t>
```

I wanto to sort the origial dictionary and I tried these:

```
<t t-foreach="widget.renderer.state.fields.sorted(key=lambda x: x.string)" t-as="field">
  <t t-esc="widget.renderer.state.fields[field].string" />
</t>
```

but I got the error: **QWeb2: Error evaluating template: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try replacing ( and ) by &#40; and  &#41; maybe

Comment: @Harlan: thanks for suggestion but it doesn't work; I tried other syntax using single quotes and the &apos; or &#39; code without success. I suppose that is a problem with the JS interpreter but don't know how to get out.

Comment: There must be something tricky with calling a function or using a lambda from a template... As a workaround you can try sorting the list in python or JS and giving it as an argument when calling the template, or create a function that will take a list as parameter and sort it using your lambda, then call this function from the template.

Comment: @Harlan: creating a specific dictionary sorted as necessary was my first thinking and probabily these will be the solution. I don't know very well the Odoo framework but are you sure that I can manipulate the list in JS before calling the template? Doing it in python have mutch sense for me.
In any case I remain with the curiosity to know why these error appears.